# Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am getting the following error while searcing for an entity after successful login

> Full authentication is required to access this resource unauthorized

I tried to correlate the items in response headers (`VCAP_ID`, `JSESSIONID`) but nothing works.  I also observed that the

```
"sessionToken":"Undefined"
```

Please provide resolution.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Double check your correlation post processors using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to ensure that all variables are properly extracted. The latter one allows inspecting request and response details as well and has i.e. RegExp Tester mode allowing validating your Regular Expressions against server response without having to re-run the request

If after all you won't fell comfortable with handling dynamic parameters in JMeter you can try out an alternative option of JMeter scripts recording which is capable of exporting the recorded test in "SmartJMX" mode automatically detecting and handling any dynamic values. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.